# How can I tell premium cars apart from standard ones?

Tags: gran-turismo-6

In GT6, the divide between "Premium cars" (cars with fully-rendered cockpit views and higher-polygon exterior models) and "Standard cars" (cars with generic shadowed cockpit views and lower-polygon exterior models) still seems to exist. Since I like playing in cockpit view mostly, I'd like to stick to cars with fully-modeled interiors most of the time.

However, I haven't seen a way to tell which cars are "Premium" and which ones are not, both when I'm shopping for a car and when I'm browsing my personal car list. Is there an easy way to identify Premium cars in these situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Dealerships/Showroom, the "Gallery View" option is ghosted (unavailable) for the "standard" cars, while the "premium" ones will have this option available. I think this is a pretty fool-proof way of detection.

A little harder perhaps, but you can also spot the difference in the Dealerships pages, by recognizing the less transparent greenish tinted window glass of the "standard" cars. On the "premium" cars you can see the modeled interior through the glass.

**Update:** It seems the latest GT6 update (1.04) now finally shows a badge for each car in the Dealerships, stating if the car has a detailed interior or not.

Answer (score 1):

Also beware, as the BMW M4 has a gallery view, yet is standard in its cockpit view. Same goes with the Vision GT Mercedes, galley but no cockpit. I haven't encountered a car that is opposite yet, so that's good news. Also in the thumbnails, standard cars have an almost greenish tint to their almost opaque windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly AFAIK there is no easy way to differentiate premium cars from standard cars. I'm in the same situation as you. I only drive from the cockpit and I don't want to spend millions in a car without interiors. I hope they fix this in a patch.

Comment: Seems PDF heard your prayers, 1.04 makes it very clear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to what has been told, another easy way to spot them is to check the windshield in the thumbnail. If the rear view mirror is visible, then it's a fully detailed car.